# Can we make two router.js file in a single angular project?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am having a situation in my Angular UI routing project while rendering the view. I have to make two router.js files. Is it possible to have two router.js files in same project. What are the cons of doing this?

Comment: you can, they are gonna be "merged" and observed as one by the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple routing files but it depends on the need. You can have separate routing file per module

Comment: Wont it affect my application?

Comment: @AnkitSaxena it shouldn't affect anything. All that matters is the `module` or `app` name where the routes are registered.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple route files and declare them in app.js

Create files route1.js and route2.js(in route directory) and add them in app.js as follows:

```
var routes1 = require('./routes/routes1');
var routes2 = require('./routes/routes2');
```

Define the route:

```
app.use('/one',routes1);
app.use('/two',routes2);
```

Now the api call of type `http://something.com/one/myroutename` will be redirected to route1.js and `http://something.com/two/myroutename` will be redirected to route2.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. This is what I normally do. Every component/view has separate route file. Remeber to add these to your index.html.

app.js

```
angular.module('App', ['App.Configs']);
angular.module('App.Configs', []);
```

routeOne.route.js

```
angular.module('App.Configs')
    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider
            .when('/routeOne', {
                template: '<route-one></reoute-one>',
                caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })
    }]);
```

routeTwo.route.js

```
angular.module('App.Configs')
    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider
            .when('/routeTwo', {
                template: '<route-two></reoute-two>',
                caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })
    }]);
```